# Trying to inherit from CloudBlobController causes 404 error

Tags: .net, azure-storage

I'm trying to write a class that extends `CloudBlobController` from the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob` namespace.

The class is:

```
Public Class BlobController(Of T)
    Inherits CloudBlobContainer

    Public Sub New(BlobStoreName As String)
        MyBase.New(New Uri(IO.Path.Combine(
                   CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.
                        GetSetting("StorageConnectionString")).BlobEndpoint.AbsoluteUri, 
                        BlobStoreName.ToLower)),
                   New Auth.StorageCredentials(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString")))
        CreateIfNotExists()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The call to the base class initializer is successful and I can see the properties of the class in the Watch window. The Uri matches the blob container that already exits but a 404 error results on the `CreateIfNotExits` call.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so as I was reviewing the data to post this question I worked out the answer so I'll post it for anyone else that makes the same idiotic mistake.

I noted that the **authentication method was set to SharedKey but the credentials were SAS!**

The fix is to call the right initializer of `Auth.StorageCredentials`:

```
New Auth.StorageCredentials(CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.
                                GetSetting("StorageConnectionString")).
                                Credentials.AccountName,
                            CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.
                                GetSetting("StorageConnectionString")).
                                Credentials.ExportKey))
```